# Confidence Interval badly worded problem????

Tags: probability, confidence-interval

This is a question I have received and do not understand if I am wrong or the actualy question is worded wrong?

Question 3

A survey of mortgage holders at the current time shows that 14% are in arrears with their mortgage repayments.

Out of the 300 people surveyed, 48% report that they are currently able to manage, while some in the sample also report that although they are not in arrears, they fear for the future.

Infer a 95% confidence interval for the proportion of all mortgage holders who are currently in arrears with their mortgage repayments.

```
Survey showed that 14% are in area where there are mortgage repayments

Out of the 300 people surveyed 

48% are able to pay back their mortgage 

52% say they cannot repay their mortgage  

N = 300
P= 48
Q = 1- 48 = 52

√(48*52/300) = 0.028
95% Z_Score = 1.96
1.96 * 0.028 = .056
14%+/-5.6%
```

Comment: The wording of the question certainly leaves a lot to be desired.  I would read it as saying that, out of the $300$ individuals surveyed, $42$ (i.e. $14\%$) are in arrears on their mortgage payments, and  $144$ (i.e. $48\%$) reported that they were "currently able to manage".   It's not at all clear to me whether those who reported being afraid of the future included any of those who also reported being currently able to manage, or whether *all* of the remaining $114$ individuals (i.e. $38\%$) belong to this category.

Comment: This is a basically sensible approach, though [there are others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval).  Why did you choose $\sqrt{48 \times 52 /300}$ for the standard error? (incidentally having calculated $0.028$, you then used $0.025$)

Answer (score 1):

As I read it, the $48 \%$ is a red herring.  The only relevant quantities
are $300$ and $14\%$.  So you have a random
sample of size $n = 300$ from a population with probability $p$ of ``success'' (defined as being in arrears), with $x = 0.14 \times 300 = 42$ successes in the sample.
You'll probably want to use the normal approximation to the binomial...

Comment: @ Robert Israel: Thanks that is some hi-tec vocabulary you have going on, so the way the professor wants it done is through the formula I have in the question. So from what I gather is `n = 300`,`p = 14` and `q = 86`????